# How to secure barbed 1/8" fitting?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, safety, hose

What would be a good way to make sure a 1/8" plastic tube doesn't come off a barbed fitting? (It's under pressure from a water tank.)

I was thinking of a clamp with a tightening screw, but they don't seem to come in such small size. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: As far as I know, a cable tie is a common solution.

Comment: If you can, use a compression fitting rather than a barb. They make a much more reliable connection for small diameter tubes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wire spring type hose clamp. They make them in many sizes, including 1/8". They work well initially and have the added benefit of applying constant tension even if the hose softens or shrinks (as opposed to a zip-tie or worm-drive hose clamp).

[image]

Comment: I like this answer. Those are the sort of clamps often used on car engine hoses.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is a good starting point. However you may want to look at using this style of spring hose clamp. They exert their pressure over a greater area of the hose and depending upon the hose material prevent cracking of the hose material as it ages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A nylon zip-tie works just fine, too.  That’s what I’m using in my computer for a few connections that have barbs rather than compression fittings.